# Sending multi-touch events over Websockets

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, websocket

I'm trying to encode the touch event object as JSON to send it over websockets, an error appears saying:

Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Error occurs when you have a property of the object which is the object itself directly. So, what's the way to send multi-touch events over websockets?

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
  console.log(event);
  event = JSON.stringify(event.touches); // Error!
  connection.send(event);
}, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PAVtk/

Comment: Why sending a string? Why not sending the JSON as is?

Comment: You could use a placeholder instead of the object to avoid circular reference then, on the server side, you could rebuild your object properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to stringify multiple [Touch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Touch) objects. These objects contains a reference to the element on which the touch started. HTMLElements often have circular references.

You should delete the element from the touch object before you send it to the server. You may want to clone it before.

```
delete touchObject["target"];
```

Comment: No you should delete target from each touches.